# CSS overflow disappears unless PHP error is triggered

Tags: php, css

I'm experiencing some weird behaviour with PHP and CSS. If I don't get an error in my PHP code (for instance when I have error reporting turned off), my overflow on the page is completely hidden and it won't let me scroll.

This is what I mean:

With error reporting turned on:

[image]

Without it:

[image]

As you can see it just totally disappears for no reason. I haven't changed the CSS at all. I've done some digging on the web and only seen this reported once. That report can be found here and all the PHP dev does is deny its a bug... https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35676

Does anyone have any clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: `php` runs on server, `css` runs in browser.. it is not a bug of `php`, as it only creates text output for the browser! the only problem is with your html/css code, which you did not show.

Comment: php doesn't know anything at all about the structure of your php, and it simply dumps its html/error message without regards to your page. If the error occurs at an unfortunately spot of your document, you WILL end up with invalid html. That's not php's fault. it's properly reporting the error. Is your fault for not handling the error, allowing php to output that message.

Comment: I'm aware of this cheery, but I still don't know why this is happening. Can anyone explain it if I post my CSS/HTML maybe? Thanks

Comment: The second commenter is correct, if error message is returned at the first line (before doctype, for example) or somewhere else in the wrong place - it breaks the structure of the html code. Which becomes invalid and browser can render it in some other way. Production server should not show any programming language related error messages.

Comment: OK I've changed my code to remove the error (as it was outputting before the doctype), however I've still got the issue of the scroll bar (along the X axis) refusing to show even though I've set the body width to 2000px

Comment: Recreate a problem at jsfiddle.net, for example, and give us a link. Show some code - we do not have telepathic abilities )

Comment: Thanks Cheery, here's a link to the outputted HTML! http://jsfiddle.net/0zrso7x2/ Cheers

Comment: It does not recreate your problem. I see nothing the same as on your images.

Comment: Sorry I got the class name wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/0zrso7x2/1/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/0zrso7x2/2/

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
}
body, html{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    background: rgba(238,238,238,.98);  
    width: 10000px; 
    z-index: 1;
}

.left-sidebar{
    width: 200px;
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: #272727;
    border-right: 1px solid #3D3D3D;
}
```